# How to create function for data.table

Tags: r, function, data.table

I want to create a function used for data.table.  Supposed we have

```
library(data.table)    
DT = data.table(x=rep(c("a","b","c"),each=3), y=c(1,3,6), v=1:9)

    foo <- function(data, field, grp){
      data[, field, by=grp]
    }
```

I have tried

```
   foo(DT, .N, grp = y)
```

or

```
   foo(DT, y)
```

They return errors.  How do I pass input arguments in the data.table?

Comment: The function already exists, like `data.table:::\`[.data.table\`(DT, j=.N, by=y)`. I doubt that you need to use it like this, though. What does it gain you to use `foo` rather than the `[]`s?

Comment: @Frank I am trying to call DTs with the same `by`. I am wondering if we could create function to help it.

Answer (score 1):

You are in essence asking to reinvent the function `[.data.table`. The `[` function perform an implicit evaluation of the second argument, `j`, in the context of the datatable. In the case of getting counts by groups it's just:

```
DT[ ,.N, by=y]
   y N
1: 1 3
2: 3 3
3: 6 3
```

Had you wanted sequences by groups it could have been:

```
> DT[ ,1:.N, by=y]
   y V1
1: 1  1
2: 1  2
3: 1  3
4: 3  1
5: 3  2
6: 3  3
7: 6  1
8: 6  2
9: 6  3
```